# DatePicker change language of confirm and cancel buttons

Tags: react-native, datepicker

I am using DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker' and it is working fine. But, the issue is I could not able to change the button text language from chinese to english and the second thing is I am getting the warning which I cant understand.[image]

[image]

Here is the code.

```
<DatePicker 
    style={styles.datePickerStyle}
    date={selectedDate}
    locale={"en"}
    // cancelDisabled = {'true'}
    mode="date"
    format="YYYY-MMM-DD"
    useNativeDriver={'true'}
    placeholder="Start Date"
    customStyles={{
        dateInput:{
            borderWidth: 0,
            alignItems: "flex-start"
        }
    }}
    onDateChange={(date) => {setSelectedDate(date)}}
    iconComponent={
        <CalendarIcon2 
            size={25}
            color='#00667E' 
            name='calendar-blank' 
        />
    }
/>
```

Comment: Actually, I fixed one issue of changing text `cancelBtnText = {'Cancel'} confirmBtnText={"Confirm"}`. But please help me with the warning.